# Traceback with odoo and google calendar

Tags: odoo, google-calendar-api, openerp-8

I have configured my Odoo app to work with Google Calendar. Now, I can add new events from my Odoo calendar, it's synch with google.
When i'm on a customer page, I have a calendar icon to add a meet. When I add an event and synch, I have [this callback](http://dpaste.com/1ANAHJC)

An idea on where does it comes from ?

Thanks

Comment: actually it came from method _send_mail_to_attendees from calendar.py. Which version are you working on.?

Comment: i think your mail template not found calendar.calendar_template_meeting_invitation

Comment: you're right, this was the problem. I've upgraded the calendar module and this bug is fixed but another one came up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822237/impossible-to-synch-odoo-with-google-calendar