# Impossible to synch odoo with google calendar

Tags: odoo, google-calendar-api, openerp-8

I've configured my odoo to sync calendar with google calendar with my api client ID and secret.
The point is, when I click on the synch button, I've this [traceback](http://dpaste.com/3KH60S9)

Does anyone has had this problem ?
It's not a duplicate of the another question. The old one is fixed, it's related to a missing mail template, here, the problem seems to be linked to JSON but I don't know why.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traceback with odoo and google calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804445/traceback-with-odoo-and-google-calendar)

Comment: nope it's not, bugs may be related but are bot the same.